# How do I use RunWith to specify a Suite of test methods?

Tags: junit4

I have something like the following:

```
@RunWith(AllTestsRunner.class)
public class AllTests {

}
```

in which AllTestsRunner is a Suite that will return all test classes within the same package as AllTests.  This works fine, but I would like to have finer-grained control than to just specify what the test classes are; I would like to be able to specify the test methods to be run (some of the test methods are annotated with `@Category(Manual.class)` and these shouldn't be run in the continuous integration system).  Is it possible to specify the Runner for AllTests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
@RunWith(Categories.class)
@Categories.ExcludeCategory(Manual.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses(AllTests.class)
public class TestsToBeRunInCi {}
```